# PCIe PRST pin functionality at M2 connector (B) with SATA device (reboot detection)

Tags: pcie, sata, pci, m2

M2 connector type (key B) support PCIe ×2, SATA, USB 2.0 and 3.0, audio, UIM, HSIC, SSIC, I2C and SMBus.

I want to use **SATA** interface with my device, but I need to **detect the reboot of the host machine** (at my SATA device).

PCIe required **PRST#** pin (for PCIe reset). At M2 there is a separate pin for that purpose.

My question is:
Will **PRST#** be toggled during the reboot of the host machine (or at the start of the host)? Even if the connected external device will be used by SATA.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't even rely on the pin ever going high in SATA mode, because keeping the reset asserted provides a cheap method of not confusing a connected PCIe card with SATA traffic.

The SATA link will go into an error state when the host resets, and a COMMRESET/COMMINIT is required to come out of it.

Comment: do you see any other ways except to work with COMMRESET/COMMINIT commands at SATA? Actually, I will have no way to control (react at) the commands at SATA. I will have an bridge from SATA to eMMC and will have an control a flow at eMMC side.

Comment: None that work reliably, but the bridge might reset itself on loss of communication and forward this to the eMMC.